# Chrome extesnion embed iframe v3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest

So I have a Chrome extension that allows me to embed multiple websites in v2 that I have to move to v3, the problem is that I don't really understand how it should work.

Code:

this is background.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    function(details) {
      var responseHeaders = details.responseHeaders;
      for (var i = 0; i < responseHeaders.length; i++) {
        if (responseHeaders[i].name.toLowerCase() === 'x-frame-options') {
          responseHeaders.splice(i, 1);
          break;
        }
      }
      return { responseHeaders: responseHeaders };
    },
    { urls: ['<all_urls>'] },
    ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']
  );
```

this is manifest v2

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "",
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/; object-src 'self'",
    "description": "Open multiple websites in new tabs when you start a new tab",
    "icons": {
      "16": "icon16.png",
      "48": "icon48.png",
      "128": "icon128.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "storage",
      "webRequest",
      "webRequestBlocking",
      "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": true
    },
    "browser_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png"
      }
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }]
  }
```

this is content.js

```
chrome.storage.sync.get({ websites: [] }, function(result) {
    var websites = result.websites;

    // Check if current URL matches any website in the list
    if (websites.includes(window.location.href)) {
      // Open all websites in new tabs
      for (var i = 0; i < websites.length; i++) {
        if (websites[i] !== window.location.href) {
          window.open(websites[i], '_blank');
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

I also have a git repo for this if anyone needs it